# How do forward_list,set,list etc call std::allocator?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

I notice that allocator can only allocate objects of type `T` and reserve blocks of memory of size `n * sizeof(T)`. Linked list nodes inside of the `std::list<T>` type, however, aren't necessarily objects of type `T`, nor are they necessarily the same size as `T` objects. In that case, how can `std::list` use `std::allocator` to allocate memory?

Comment: By using `std::allocator<T>::rebind` and setting `n` to 1. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why the [rebind type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) exists. It allows you to create a similar allocator that instead allocates something else (like a `node<T>` for example).

Basically like this:

```
std::allocator<int> int_alloc;
std::allocator<int>::rebind<node<int>> node_alloc;
//Perhaps more useful:
decltype(int_alloc)::rebind<node<int>> node_alloc;
```

Of course, in a real situation this would all be templated, but hopefully this shows the idea.

For more information, read the notes and examples [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).